# Accessing member of a class with atomic private variables in another class

Tags: c++, vector, atomic

I am trying to access atomic private variables defined in `class A` using vector of objects . This vector of objects is passed by value in other `class B` defined in another header file. While  retrieving the the value from vector I am getting the value as `0`

I have few `std::atomic` private variables in a class say class A

**A.hpp** file

```
class A
{ 
  public: 
  vector<A> updatePktCount();
  private:
  std::atomic pktCount;
  std::atomic recvPkt;
  std::atomic droppedPkt;

};
```

**A.cpp**

// there will be different pkts for different ports 
    vector a[2]; // 2 since I have 2 port ID's

```
vector<A> A::updatePktCount(int portId) 
{  a.push_back(A());
  //some function that gets packet details based on portId
  pktCount = getPacketCount(int portID, int recvPkt,int pktCount,int droppedPkt); 
  pktCount = pktCount++;
  recvPkt  = recvPkt++;
  droppedPkt = droppedPkt++; 

  a.push_back(A());

  return a; 
}
```

Class B in different header file `B.hpp`

```
class B: public A {

   void getPacketCountFromA();
};
```

`B.cpp` file

```
void B::getPacketCountFromA()
{
   vector<A> storeValue; 
   A a; 
   storeValue = a.updatePktCount();
   for(auto i = storeValue.begin(); i != storeValue.end(); ++i)
   {
      // print values
   }
}
```

I have created a vector of objects in A like `vector<A> a[2]` for 2 portId but when I retrieve this vector in `getPacketCountFromA` I am getting the vector size as `2` but all the values in the vector is `0`

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

> Result
>
> size of vector is 2 
>   pktCount   = 0
>   recvPkt    = 0
>   droppedPkt = 0

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you create a minimal example which recreates your problem? In doing so, you might solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @DeiDei I am sorry that the question is not clear the `updatePktCount` function updates the packet for a `portId` and stores this value in instance. A new instance is spawned for every portId there are 2 ports in my case. So my design intent is store this instance in vector of objects of `class A` and retrieve this value from other `class B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recvPkt  = recvPkt++;` is retrieving the value of `recvPkt`, increment `recvPkt`, then store the retrieved value (`0`) back into `recvPkt`, losing the effect of the increment.  Just increment the value:

```
++recvPkt;
```

The same for your other variables.

Comment: That was so simple thank you :) ok for design purpose do you think vector should be call by value or call by reference when exposing this vector in other class